# Delete a class with vector<const char *> in C++

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

class TList {
    std::vector<const char*> elementos;
    int position;
public:
    TList(const char** e, int s);
};

TList::TList(const char** e, int s)
{
     std::vector<const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);
     elementos = res;
     position = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    const char *arr[2] = {"Hola", "AAAA"};
    TList *list = new TList(arr, size);
    delete[]list;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Visual Studio and it reach the "delete[]list;" line, it says "Exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0xD8D6A9B0" in the file "xutility" at the line 253, here:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy != 0)
```

What is the problem? and what can I do?

Comment: The problem is when it is deleting the list in "delete[]list;"

Comment: Don't deallocate something allocated with `new` with `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

class TList {

private:
    std::vector<const char*> elementos;
    int position;

public:
    TList(const char** e, int s);
    ~TList() {}
};

TList :: TList(const char** e, int s) {
    std::vector <const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);
    elementos = res;
    position = 0;
}

int main() {
    int size = 2;
    const char * arr[2] = {"Hola", "AAAA"};
    TList * list = new(std::nothrow) TList(arr, size);
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

The reason the other wasn't working was because list wasn't an array. You use 'delete []' is when you have arrays of allocated memory.

Comment: It works but if you change "std::vector <const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s - 1]);" and put "std::vector <const char*> res (&e[0], &e[s]);"

Comment: Yeah, that was  just a trouble shooting thing that I did. Sorry!

Comment: Why does this thing have a destructor? `&e[s]` is undefined behaviour when `e` points to `arr` from `main()` and `s == 2`.

Comment: Because everyone always forgets them when they need them. It's better to put it in and not have it than leave it out and need it. the thing about '&e[s]' was just a mistake, I don't know.

Comment: No one needs a destructor with an empty body. `&e[s]` is still undefined behaviour, use `e + s` instead.

Comment: "It's better to put it in and not have it than leave it out and need it." When your class needs a destructor then it needs a copy constructor, too. Why didn't you put that in?